# How to optimise this ActiveRecord query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm still learning ruby, rails and ActiveRecord everyday. Right now I'm learning SQL through a new small app I'm building but the problem is that the main view of my app currently does ~2000 queries per page refresh, oouuuppps.

So now that I know I have all the required information in my DB and that I can display them correctly, it is time for me to optimise them but I just don't know where to start to be honest.

These are my models associations

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :league_teams
  has_many :teams, :through => :league_teams
end


class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :gameweeks
  has_many :league_teams
  has_many :leagues, :through => :league_teams
end


class Gameweek < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
  has_and_belongs_to_many :substitutes, class_name: "Player", join_table: "gameweeks_substitutes"
  belongs_to :captain, class_name: "Player"
  belongs_to :vice_captain, class_name: "Player"
end


class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :event_explain
  serialize :fixtures
  serialize :fixture_history
  has_many :gameweeks, class_name: "captain"
  has_many :gameweeks, class_name: "vice_captain"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :gameweeks
  has_many :player_fixtures
end
```

So this is my controller:

```
@league = League.includes(teams: [{gameweeks: [{players: :player_fixtures} , :captain]}]).find_by(fpl_id:params[:fpl_id])
@teams = @league.teams
@defense_widget_leaderboard = @league.position_based_leaderboard_stats(@teams, ['Defender', 'Goalkeeper'])
```

And this is one of the method in my League Model:

```
  def position_based_leaderboard_stats(teams,positions_array)
    leaderboard = []

    teams.each do |team|
      position_points = 0
      gameweeks = team.gameweeks

      gameweeks.each do |gameweek|
        defense = gameweek.players.where(type_name:positions_array)

        defense.each do |player|
          player.player_fixtures.where(gw_number: gameweek.number).each do |p|
            position_points += p.points
          end
        end
      end
      leaderboard << [team.team_name,position_points]
    end
    return leaderboard.sort_by {|team| team[1]}.reverse
  end
```

I have 4 methods that look more or less the same thing as the one above. Each are doing between 300 and 600 queries.

As far as I read it only, it is a typical case of N+1 queries. I tried to reduce with the includes in the @league but it got me down from 2000 to 1800 queries.

I looked into `group_by`, `joins` and `sum` but I couldn't make it work.

The closest thing I got to working was this

```
players = PlayerFixture.group("player_id").sum(:points)
```

Where I could then query by doing `players[player.id]` but that doesn't give me the right results anyway because it doesn't take into account the Gameweeks > Players > Player_fixtures relationship.

How can I reduce the numbers of queries I'm doing? I went on #RubyOnRails on freenode and people told me it can be done in 1 query but wouldn't point me in any directions or help me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spend some time with SQL. Finally found the query that can help me with that. I also discovered SQL Views and how to [use them through Activerecord](http://alexpotrykus.com/blog/2013/04/10/postgres-views-in-rails/) which is pretty neat.

Final successful query

```
CREATE VIEW team_position_points AS

select teams.id as team_id, teams.team_name, players.type_name, sum(points) as points
from teams 
inner join gameweeks on teams.id = gameweeks.team_id    
inner join gameweeks_players on gameweeks.id = gameweeks_players.gameweek_id
inner join players on gameweeks_players.player_id = players.id
inner join player_fixtures on players.id = player_fixtures.player_id AND player_fixtures.gw_number = gameweeks.number
group by teams.id, players.type_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `position_based_leaderboard_stats` N+1 problem appears, too. So you can preload all your associations before `each` cycles:

```
def position_based_leaderboard_stats(teams,positions_array)
  leaderboard = []
  Team.preload(gameweeks: players).where('players.type_name=?', positions_array )
  your code
```

Also, you could add player_fixtures to `preload` statement, but I can't understand dependencies of those associations, sorry.

Comment: Just tried and it doesn't change anything. The method still do ~640 queries.

Comment: I've made a typo: it should be (gameweeks: :players) instead of (gameweeks: players). Did you fix it?

Comment: Yep, I fixed your typo. Still doesn't change anything to the number of queries :/